# Variable value gets reset to initialized value in Objective-c/Cocos-2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I declared a BOOL in a ".h" file and initialized it to FALSE in ".m" and I set it to TRUE, under a very specific condition and I expect it to be TRUE from then on.

But, the `BOOL` value keeps getting reset to the initial value of FALSE at every frame.
When I print an output of the `BOOL` value at every update, I get something like this:

```
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
//Condition gets true
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

I am not setting the BOOL anywhere else in the whole code.

I am a little bit new to Objective-C, so please help me out. Does this have to do something with the way variables are defined?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in every line where you assign a value to the BOOL. Something is setting it back to NO. There's no magic behind it, just a coding bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your FALSE statement is being called on a 'timer', or a function that is repeatedly called; the same for your true statement. Check and make sure your calls are not repeated, or try and put them in different places.